# Can't find wireless networks - Netgear WN311B, 12.04

Tags: 12.04, wireless, networking, netgear

I'm using a Netgear WN311B PCI wireless adapter on my desktop. 
The device works without problems under Windows (dual boot).

I have enabled the Broadcom STA wireless drivers in "Additional Drivers".

This is the output of /etc/log/syslog when I enable wireless in the Wicd dialog:

```
May  6 16:50:41 cosine NetworkManager[816]: <info> WiFi now enabled by radio killswitch
May  6 16:50:41 cosine NetworkManager[816]: <info> (eth2): bringing up device.
May  6 16:50:41 cosine wpa_supplicant[2693]: nl80211: 'nl80211' generic netlink not found
May  6 16:50:41 cosine NetworkManager[816]: <info> (eth2): supplicant interface state: starting -> ready
May  6 16:50:41 cosine NetworkManager[816]: <info> (eth2): device state change: unavailable -> disconnected (reason 'supplicant-available') [20 30 42]
May  6 16:50:41 cosine NetworkManager[816]: <info> (eth2): supplicant interface state: ready -> inactive
May  6 16:50:41 cosine NetworkManager[816]: <warn> Trying to remove a non-existant call id.
May  6 16:50:42 cosine avahi-daemon[795]: Joining mDNS multicast group on interface eth2.IPv6 with address fe80::21f:33ff:feb3:b184.
May  6 16:50:42 cosine avahi-daemon[795]: New relevant interface eth2.IPv6 for mDNS.
May  6 16:50:42 cosine avahi-daemon[795]: Registering new address record for fe80::21f:33ff:feb3:b184 on eth2.*.
```

This is the result when I run "sudo iwlist eth2 scan":
    eth2      No scan results

This is the output of lsmod:

```
Module                  Size  Used by                                                                                                                                                                                                         
wl                   2568210  0                                                                                                                                                                                                               
nvidia              12319264  40                                                                                                                                                                                                              
rfcomm                 47604  0                                                                                                                                                                                                               
snd_hda_codec_via      51398  1                                                                                                                                                                                                               
bnep                   18281  2                                                                                                                                                                                                               
bluetooth             180104  10 rfcomm,bnep                                                                                                                                                                                                  
parport_pc             32866  0                                                                                                                                                                                                               
snd_hda_intel          33773  3                                                                                                                                                                                                               
ppdev                  17113  0                                                                                                                                                                                                               
snd_hda_codec         127706  2 snd_hda_codec_via,snd_hda_intel                                                                                                                                                                               
lib80211_crypt_tkip    17390  0                                                                                                                                                                                                               
snd_usb_audio         122982  1                                                                                                                                                                                                               
snd_pcm                97188  3 snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,snd_usb_audio                                                                                                                                                                     
uvcvideo               72627  0                                                                                                                                                                                                               
videodev               98259  1 uvcvideo                                                                                                                                                                                                      
snd_hwdep              13668  2 snd_hda_codec,snd_usb_audio                                                                                                                                                                                   
snd_usbmidi_lib        25395  1 snd_usb_audio                                                                                                                                                                                                 
psmouse                87692  0                                                                                                                                                                                                               
v4l2_compat_ioctl32    17128  1 videodev                                                                                                                                                                                                      
snd_seq_midi           13324  0                                                                                                                                                                                                               
snd_rawmidi            30748  2 snd_usbmidi_lib,snd_seq_midi                                                                                                                                                                                  
joydev                 17693  0 
lib80211               14381  2 wl,lib80211_crypt_tkip
snd_seq_midi_event     14899  1 snd_seq_midi
serio_raw              13211  0 
snd_seq                61896  2 snd_seq_midi,snd_seq_midi_event
asus_atk0110           18078  0 
snd_timer              29990  2 snd_pcm,snd_seq
snd_seq_device         14540  3 snd_seq_midi,snd_rawmidi,snd_seq
snd                    78855  19             snd_hda_codec_via,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,snd_usb_audio,snd_pcm,snd_hwdep,snd_usbmidi_lib,snd_rawmidi,snd_seq,snd_timer,snd_seq_device
soundcore              15091  1 snd
snd_page_alloc         18529  2 snd_hda_intel,snd_pcm
mac_hid                13253  0 
lp                     17799  0 
parport                46562  3 parport_pc,ppdev,lp
vesafb                 13844  1 
r8169                  62099  0 
usbhid                 47199  0 
hid                    99559  1 usbhid
```

This is the output of "sudo lshw -C network":

```
*-network               
   description: Ethernet interface
   product: RTL8111/8168B PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet controller
   vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
   logical name: eth0
   version: 02
   serial: 48:5b:39:d1:74:b4
   size: 1Gbit/s
   capacity: 1Gbit/s
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list rom ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
   configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=full firmware=N/A ip=192.168.0.2 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=MII speed=1Gbit/s
   resources: irq:44 ioport:e800(size=256) memory:f8eff000-f8efffff memory:f8ee0000-f8eeffff memory:feaf0000-feafffff
*-network
   description: Wireless interface
   product: BCM4321 802.11b/g/n
   vendor: Broadcom Corporation
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:04:00.0
   logical name: eth2
   version: 01
   serial: 00:1f:33:b3:b1:84
   width: 32 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: bus_master ethernet physical wireless
   configuration: broadcast=yes driver=wl0 driverversion=5.100.82.38 latency=64   multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11bgn
   resources: irq:16 memory:febfc000-febfffff
```

I'm at a loss. I've tried using wicd, without results. I've tried removing and reinstalling the card. I've tried removing the driver and modprobing it. I've tried disabling the STA driver.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I have had this same problem for a while with my laptop.  Upon installation I have to connect with wired connection and uninstall the broadcom sta drivers and install the [b43-fwcutter](http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/b43-fwcutter) package instead.  You also need the [firmware-b43-installer package](http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/firmware-b43-installer).  It is possible to download the packages and dependencies and  install them manually, but I have had much better luck installing with through the wired adapter.